# ZF2 send mail always get error [Could not open socket]

Tags: php, sockets, email, zend-framework2

I am using Zend Mail to send out an email from Zimbra.

```
        $message = new \Zend\Mail\Message();
        $message->setBody("test");
        $message->setFrom("febri.damatraseta@mydomainzimbra.com");
        $message->setSubject("Trying to send an email");
        $message->addTo("febryfairuz@gmail.com");

        $smtpOptions = new \Zend\Mail\Transport\SmtpOptions();
        $smtpOptions->setHost("192.123.456.789:01")
                    ->setConnectionClass('login')
                    ->setName('192.123.456.789:01')
                    ->setConnectionConfig(array(
                        'username'  => 'febri.damatraseta@mydomainzimbra.com',
                        'password'  => '123abc',
                        'ssl'       => 'tls'
                    ));
        $transport = new \Zend\Mail\Transport\Smtp($smtpOptions);
        $transport->send($message);
```

I receive this error:

`Could not open socket`

and i have OpenSSL installed.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

I fall into the same issue a few weeks ago, this is the correct usage:

```
// Setup SMTP transport using LOGIN authentication
        $transport = new SmtpTransport ();
        $options = new SmtpOptions ( array (
                'name' => 'whatever.com',
                'host' => 'smtp',
                'connection_class' => 'plain',
                'port' => '587', // Notice port change for TLS is 587
                'connection_config' => array (
                        'username' => '',
                        'password' => '',
                        'ssl' => 'tls' 
                ) 
        ) );
        $transport->setOptions ( $options );
        $transport->send ( $message );
```